# showing a new Form Using a public function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In my application I have to show lot of forms when particular button/panels are clicked. so instead of writing

```
Frm = New formname
Frm.MdiParent = MDIParent
Frm.Show()
```

i want to have public function through which i can pass the form name.
for that i have written a function

```
Public Sub showForm(ByVal formname As Form)
        Frm = New formname
        Frm.MdiParent = MDIParent1
        Frm.Show()
    End Sub
Call showForm(myformname)
```

but problem with this is, it says formname is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I updated my answer to reflect your comment that a form should only be opened once.

> I want to have public function through which i can pass the **form name**.
>   for that i have written a function

`Public Sub showForm(ByVal formname As Form)`

You don´t pass the name of a form to your function but an object of type `Form` instead.

Here is one possible solution with a generic version of `showForm`:

```
Public Class FormManager
  Private _formByName As New Dictionary(Of String, Form)

  Public Sub showForm(Of T As {Form, New})(name As String, parent As Form)
      Dim frm As Form = Nothing
      If Not _formByName.TryGetValue(name, frm) OrElse _formByName(name).IsDisposed Then
          frm = New T()
          _formByName(name) = frm
      End If
      frm.MdiParent = parent
      frm.Show()
  End Sub
End Class
```

The `FormManager` holds a dictionary cache for all opened forms with `Key=form name.` This is to make sure that a form is only opened once. The check `form.IsDisposed` makes sure that you can close the form and reopen it.

Usage from the parent form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private fm = New FormManager()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        fm.showForm(Of MyForm)("MyForm", Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The first parameter is to identify the form name. The real magic is in the Type `T` which we made sure it is 1) of type or subtype `Form` and 2) it has a parameterless constructor (`MyForm` is just a placeholder for this example put in the type of your real form you want to show).

The parent parameter will bring you additional flexibility if it is not always `MDIParent1`. Remove it if you don´t neet the extra flexibility.

For sure you can also drop the `FormManager` class and put the `showForm` to another place.

Comment: its works but it opens a new every time i click...i mean if i click 10 time it ll open same form 10 times instead of once. what i saw using your code is it is working same as what i tried befor  `Public Sub showForm(ByVal formname As Form)
        Frm =  formname
        Frm.MdiParent = MDIParent1
        Frm.Show()
    End Sub
Call showForm(myformname)`  Thanks for the answer @Alex B

Comment: You never stated that in your question so I thought you want a new form to be opened every time. I will updated my code with the new requirement.

Comment: @Mps I updated my answer. Sorry that it took longer but I was busy at work.